# Why do we care about chirality?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, parity, chirality, cp-violation

I'm trying to figure out what's the importance of chirality in QFT. To me it seems just something mathematical (the eigenvalue of the $\gamma^{5}$ operator ) without any physical insight in it. So my question is why do we care about Chirality, and why is it important?

Comment: Let me quote just one particular example of the importance of chirality from Wikipedia's page on "Chiral symmetry breaking": "Chiral symmetry breaking is most apparent in the mass generation of nucleons from more elementary light quarks, accounting for approximately 99% of their combined mass as a baryon. **It thus accounts for most of the mass of all visible matter.**" The page I quote is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_symmetry_breaking

Comment: To complement @Gold's comment, which refers to the QCD part of the Standard Model, I'll add that the *rest* of the Standard Model is flagrantly chiral: the $SU(2)$ gauge field couples *only* to the left-chiral fermion fields, and the $U(1)$ (hypercharge) gauge field couples asymmetrically to the left- and right-chiral gauge fields. The Standard Model is a chiral gauge theory. Maybe those things don't relate to everyday life quite as directly as the phenomenon that Gold mentioned, but it's still central to our understanding of matter.

Comment: ChiralAnomaly and Gold covered the importance of chirality very well. To try to ground it into something more concrete than "an eigenvalue of $\gamma_5$", consider looking at the world through a mirror. Before the 1960s, almost everyone assumed that the laws of physics in the "mirror world" would be the same as the laws of physics in the "real world," or loosely speaking there's no fundamental difference between left and right. Chiral symmetry breaking implies that the laws of physics *are* different in the mirror world, and at a fundamental level Nature differentiates left from right.

Comment: Good comments, they could be put together by someone who knows about this kind of thing as an answer!

Comment: So a better question might be, since the Standard Model is "flagrantly chiral", how come that the macroscopic world or even atomic scale doesn't _abound_ with chiral differences that we'd have observed much earlier? Does something surreptitiously cancel them out, or is there a deeper structural reason why chiral effects don't normally arise in bulk?

Comment: @Troposphere Because the fields and particles we actually observe at low energies _aren't_ chiral (apart from the weak nuclear force). Composites can have different properties from their constituent parts. For example, the electron field is formed out of two chiral (and massless) fermion fields, but itself is non-chiral and massive. It's kind of like we know that the strong nuclear force is very important for quarks and nuclei, but you don't really care about it in, say, chemistry. The only thing that matters in chemistry is the number of electrons and their interactions, for the most part.

Comment: @Luaan: that sounds like a "because it does" answer. Those two chiral fields that combine to form electrons must have very similar properties to begin with for their combination not to show any residual chiral behavior. Is is just luck that they happen to match up so well, or is there a conceptual reason that they _have to_?

Comment: @Troposphere Think about it more like this: if you have a left-handed thing, and you change parity, you now have a right-handed thing, and vice versa. But if you have a thing that's made of one left-handed and one right-handed thing, the parity flip doesn't change anything - you still have one left-handed and one right-handed thing. Literally no change, since the particles in the fields are indistinguishable.

Comment: @Troposphere Chirality rears its head again macroscopically in nature. Many natural organic compounds are chiral in production or interaction. Nothing to do with QFT, but it is interesting to me.

Comment: @Luaan: But why _would_ we always have both a left-handed thing and a right-handed thing at the same time _if the laws that produce those things differ_ between left-handed and right-handed? A priori one would expect that if the underlying theory is inherently chiral, then such-and-such prior conditions ought to have _different_ probabilities for producing the left-handed thing or the right-handed thing (going in any given direction).

Comment: @Troposphere Because most of the laws _don't_ distinguish between chirality; as far as we can tell, in our universe (at low energies and all that), _only_ the weak nuclear force does. Everything else is parity invariant. And as important as the weak nuclear force is to things like nuclear reactions, it's extremely weak (at a distance) and weak interactions are extremely rare. Our visible universe is absolutely dominated by the electromagnetic and gravitational interactions, because the strong nuclear force is so strong and the weak so weak :D

Comment: @Troposphere For example, in the standard model, the electron field is a result of the coupling between two fields and the non-zero Higgs field. We often call those two fields electron-left and electron-right. All of the matter particles are like this - one left, one right. Both left and right in the pair have identical properties (similar to how an electron and a tau are the same except for their mass) _except_ for coupling to the isospin force (which is also related to the left ones having _another_ pairing - with the corresponding neutrino; there are no "right-neutrinos").

Comment: @Troposphere Interestingly in this universe with a zero Higgs field, an encounter with a Higgs particle (there's multiple in that model, but that's not important) has a very high chance of changing the left-electron into a right-electron and vice versa. In our universe, with a non-zero Higgs field, this manifests as a sort of constant flipping between the two - giving the electron its mass (both left- and right-electron are massless). And again, only the left participate in the weak interaction (this leaves the possibility that right-neutrinos do exist, but interact with nothing but gravity).

Comment: @Troposphere Why does this hierarchy exist? We don't know, just like we don't know if there's an underlying fundamental reason that there's three leptons and neutrinos (with the same properties except for mass) and three up- and down-quarks (with the same properties except for mass). There doesn't _have_ to be an underlying reason - though we keep looking for it. We still don't know if there's just one possible way for the laws of the universe to exist or not - and if not, the only thing special about ours is that it makes a universe like our possible; but there could be others with no stars.

Comment: @Luaan: Very well -- but it sounds to me like your description is at odds with the claim by Chiral Anomaly that "the rest of the Standard Model is flagrantly chiral" which sounded like _all_ of the fundamental interactions are inherently chiral, so it would only be by pure luck that they combine to produce mirror-symmetric behavior at the macroscopic level. If I'm understanding correctly (which I might not be), the electromagnetic force comes by as some kind of emergent combination of the electroweak SU(2) and U(1) fields, which Chiral Anomaly said _both_ are fundamentally chiral.

Answer (score 12):

I'll give a slightly more mathematical answer. First let me expand upon what chirality is all about. Quantum fields transform on specific representations of the Lorentz group. The irreducible representations are known as the $(A,B)$ representations and they are labelled by two integers or half-integers $A$ and $B$. If you have never seem this, please see Weinberg's The Quantum Theory of Fields Chapter 5.

The representations $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ and $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ are the Weyl representations. Fields transforming on those representations have spin $\frac{1}{2}$, thereby being fermions, and are known as *chiral fermions*. The ones in the $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ representation are called left-handed Weyl fermions and the ones in the $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ representation are called right-handed Weyl fermions. It is possible to show that these can be taken as the building blocks for all other fields, so mathematically they are already quite relevant.

The chiral fermions have the peculiar property that they are necessarily massless particles. The reason for that is that to build a Lorentz invariant mass term in a Lagrangian density it takes both an object from the $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ representation and another from the $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ representation. *A standalone chiral fermion does not admit a mass term*!

On the other hand the standard Dirac fermions, like the ones we encounter in QED, have mass. The Dirac field transforms in the representation $(\frac{1}{2},0)\oplus (0,\frac{1}{2})$ and therefore it can be understood as a composite object formed out of two chiral fermions. This is one particular instance of what I have said that they are building blocks for all representations. This is where the $\gamma^5$ story comes in: the chiral projectors applied to a Dirac field project onto the irreducible left or right handed Weyl representations.

Now making more contact with what we find in the real world, consider the Standard Model. It is a gauge theory with gauge group ${\rm SU}_{\rm C}(3)\times {\rm SU}_{\rm L}(2)\times {\rm U}_{\rm Y}(1)$. This theory is built from the ground up with chiral fermions. Consider for instance the leptons in the electroweak sector ${\rm SU}_{\rm L}(2)\times {\rm U}_{\rm Y}(1)$. One such lepton would be the electron. Since we know in the real world leptons have mass, we assign to each lepton *two chiral fermions $\ell_L$ and $\ell_R$*. But for each lepton we have one associated neutrino and the neutrino *in the Standard Model*, does not have mass. Indeed the neutrino of lepton $\ell$ gets just a single chiral left-handed fermion $\nu_\ell$.

Now do you see that little ${\rm L}$ I have written down on the ${\rm SU}(2)$ group? It is to remind ourselves that the left-handed part of each lepton, $\ell_L$, and the associated neutrino $\nu_\ell$, make up one ${\rm SU}(2)$ doublet $L_\ell=\begin{pmatrix}\nu_\ell \\ \ell_L\end{pmatrix}$. These fields are charged under ${\rm SU}(2)$, while the right-handed part of the lepton, $\ell_R$, is one ${\rm SU}(2)$ singlet, and therefore is neutral under ${\rm SU}(2)$.

In that setting, an explicit mass term for the lepton would couple $\ell_L$ and $\ell_R$ and this would be incompatible with the symmetry we have. In the end of the day, the Higgs mechanism gives rise to a mass term in the phase of broken symmetry, through the Yukawa coupling of the lepton to the Higgs field. Of course the Higgs field has the right quantum numbers so that the coupling is indeed symmetric. After all, in Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking the Lagrangian is symmetric and the symmetry is broken by the vacuum, which is not invariant.

Of course, it's not possible to give a comprehensive overview of the electroweak theory in a single answer, but I hope these brief remarks make it clear that chirality has a strong presence in the Standard Model.

Still regarding the Standard Model, there is also the QCD sector ${\rm SU}_{\rm C}(3)$ of the Standard Model, in which chiral symmetry plays a big role in the discussion of mass generation, as I have mentioned in comment.

Finally I would also like to say that in supersymmetry chiral fermions are quite natural. There are two equivalent formalisms for SUSY: one using chiral fermions, which we find for example in Wess & Bagger, and another using Majorana fermions. Since they are equivalent this ends up being a matter of taste. Personally, I find the formalism with chiral fermions to be more elegant and nicer to manipulate.

Answer (score 11):

> [Parity involves a transformation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/parity.html) that changes the algebraic sign of the coordinate system. Parity is an important idea in quantum mechanics because the wavefunctions which represent particles can behave in different ways upon transformation of the coordinate system which describes them. Under the parity transformation:

[image]

> The parity transformation changes a right-handed coordinate system into a left-handed one or vice versa. Two applications of the parity transformation restores the coordinate system to its original state.

> It is a reasonable presupposition that nature should not care whether its coordinate system is right-handed or left-handed, but surprisingly, that turns out not to be so. In a famous experiment by C. S. Wu, the non-conservation of parity in beta decay was demonstrated

.........

> subsequent experiments have consistently shown that a neutrino always has its intrinsic angular momentum (spin) pointed in the direction opposite its velocity. It is called a left-handed particle as a result. Anti-neutrinos have their spins parallel to their velocity and are therefore right-handed particles. Therefore we say that the neutrino has an intrinsic chirality.

"Chiral" is an adjective coming from the ancient greek word meaning "hand" (χείρ).

When the observed handedness of specific particles and interactions came to be described with the mathematics of Quantum Field Theory,  the "chiral" adjective was chosen, instead of "handedness". The physical insight is that having it in QFT allows the correct modeling of the data by QFT.

Comment: There's a good chance that chemists were using "chiral" for handedness before QFT was invented, and physicists may have adopted the word from chemists.

Comment: @electronpusher  Probably so, the term chirality  is extensively used in chemistry, but according to wikipedia Lord Kelvin was responsible for its invention  in English https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality .

Comment: @electronpusher It was used in geometry long before anyone knew enough chemistry to see its effects in that field.

Answer (score 3):

What distinguishes the chiral projections from other projections is that they are invariant under (commute with) continuous Lorentz transformations. Therefore, it's possible to have a theory in which only one projected "half" of the spinor exists, but which is still Lorentz invariant. That's interesting. And the real world turns out to be that way, so it's also important.

---

To motivate the projections geometrically, let me start with an easier case, which is rotation in 4+0 dimensions.

In 4 or more spatial dimensions, it's possible to have simultaneous independent (commuting) rotation in two perpendicular planes.

A general rotation in four dimensions is a rotation by different angles (which may be zero) in perpendicular planes. However, you can always write any rotation as a composition of two rotations by *equal* angles in perpendicular planes. A rotation by $θ$ in the $wx$ plane and $φ$ in the $yz$ plane is a rotation by $(θ+φ)/2$ in the $wx$ and $yz$ planes composed with a rotation by $(θ-φ)/2$ in the $wx$ and $zy$ planes, where I've reversed the order of $zy$ so that the rotation is in the opposite direction.

Furthermore, as in three dimensions, orthonormal bases in four dimensions can be classified as right- or left-handed, and you can classify equiangular rotations as right- or left-handed by whether the rotational planes "concatenated" ($wxyz$ or $wxzy$) form a right- or left-handed coordinate frame. Then every rotation decomposes not just into two equiangular rotations, but into one right-handed and one left-handed equiangular rotation.

---

In the case of massless fields in 3+1 dimensional spacetime, there is rotation in the 2D plane perpendicular to the direction of propagation, *and there is also rotation in internal dimensions* corresponding to the gauge forces.

In the simplest case, $U(1)\cong SO(2)$, there is one internal plane of rotation, so when you combine it with the spatial rotation you have two perpendicular planes, and you can decompose the rotation into equiangular rotations of opposite handedness as before. It's possible for only one of the two to exist. Conventionally, the internal rotation is represented by a complex phase; that's the reason there is a factor of $i$ in $γ^5$. There is no chiral decomposition without the internal gauge field, but in 5+1 dimensions there would be, since you would have four spatial dimensions perpendicular to propagation.

This simple chiral gauge theory is largely academic since the only physically relevant $U(1)$ gauge theory is QED, which isn't chiral.

The full gauge group of the Standard Model has a complicated structure, but it can be embedded in [SO(10)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO(10)), the group of rotations of 10-dimensional space. (Actually in Spin(10), but that's out of scope for this answer.) You therefore have in total 12 dimensions perpendicular to propagation, and rotation in 6 perpendicular planes, one external and 5 internal. It is still possible to decompose the rotation into right- and left-handed parts, though the geometric interpretation of this in more than 4 dimensions is not clear to me. It's possible for only one handedness to exist without breaking continuous Lorentz invariance, and that turns out to be true in reality.